# Am I limited to hard coding each and every screen in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating an app in python using kivy. I am basically creating a formula calculator that will allow you to click on which formula you want to solve. You input your known values into text boxes and leave one of them unknown. Then the logic will solve for the unknown value. I will need alot of different screens since there are tons and tons of different formula I will support. Or is there an oppurtunity to use just one generic screen that changes dynamically depending on which formula you want to solve? How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You mean equation not formula. That said, I would use two textboxes with respectively the left and right hand side of the equation. I would prefill both side of the equation as per user selection and let the user replace placeholders with actual values.

I would the use sympy to parse each side as an expression. See https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html. I would then build an equation out of both expressions and then have sympy solve it for me.

Going by your plan will turn to a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use a generic screen.

Make a screen with a BoxLayout, and another layout class (BoxLayout can be used here as well, if you want custom sizing go for RelativeLayout or FloatLayout) which contains both the textinput and a label for the letter of the equation.

Then you can add as many of those widgets as needed in that box layout when you call a particular method of the generic screen.

**For example**

```
<FormulaScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: formulaLayout
```

**In Screen**

```
def on_formula(self, formula):
    for value in formula:
        widget = InputWidget()
        widget.text = value
        self.ids['formulaLayout'].add_widget(widget)

def read_all(self):    # Get all textinput values from the layout
    layout_children = self.ids['formulaLayout'].children
    layout_children.reverse()
    for child in layout_children:
        print(child.textinput.text)
```

**Widget Class**

```
class FormulaInput(BoxLayout):
    orientation = 'horizontal'
    text = StringProperty("")

    label = None
    textinput = None
    
    def value_changed(self, value, instance):
        self.label.text = self.text

    def on_kv_post(self, instance):
        self.label = Label(text=self.text)
        self.add_widget(self.label)
        self.textinput = TextInput()
        self.add_widget(self.textinput)
        self.bind(text = self.value_changed)
```